# 4K 120Hz OLED 5G laptop or tablet

Tags: laptop, tablet

I'm considering getting a new daily driver, and all I want is:

- OLED screen at 4K with 120Hz. Possibly 3K.
- 5G and Wi-Fi 7. e-SIM would be a plus.
- USB-C charging.

Preferably no HDMI port, and only USB-C ports.

Is there any laptop or tablet like that?

For gaming I'll use GeForce Now.

I've found the following options:

- [HP Elite DragonFly G4](https://www.hp.com/us-en/shop/pdp/hp-elite-dragonfly-notebook-pc-g4-customizable-6q249av-mb), customized, 3k2k OLED, Wi-Fi 6E, 5G
- [Lenovo Tab Extreme](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/tablets/android-tablets/lenovo-tab-series/lenovo-tab-extreme/len103l0015), 3K OLED@120 Hz, Wi-Fi 6E, 5G

Related Reddit-thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/androidtablets/comments/18ts27g/looking_for_11_inch_oled_with_5g/

Comment: Hi Mikael, welcome to Hardware Recs! It sounds like you're looking for a thin-and-light laptop, not a gaming laptop? Do you have any preferences in terms of weight and screen size? Do  you have a budget you need to stick to?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to be the odd one with this but you should consider checking out some of the chromebooks, I know it sounds outlandish and silly but rest assured chromebooks that are out these days are actually quite good.

I don't think there is one with a 4k OLED but if you're using GeForce Now that really wouldn't matter anyways, I use a chromebook that has the ability to install linux and at first I was very skeptical but I gotta tell you there is a lot you can do with a Chromebook, I don't game on mine but as far as graphic design or podcast work or using the cloud it runs really smooth, it almost feels like a super Raspberry Pi.

It actually also has a spot for a SIM card for mobile data and once you realize the amount of things a chromebook offers the possibilities are endless.

Comment: The [Lenovo IdeaPad Duet 5](https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/lenovo-ideapad-duet-5-chromebook) looks like the Surface RT I had in high school, sadly no 5G, and the screen could have a higher resolution - my current 2-in-1 has a 13" 4K display that I use at 175% DPI.

Comment: [Lenovo Tab Extreme](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/tablets/android-tablets/lenovo-tab-series/lenovo-tab-extreme/len103l0015) might actually be exactly what I'm looking for, minus Wi-Fi 7 support (but has 6E). It even has two USB-C ports!

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder will be honest I didn't know WiFi 7 was currently available considering WiFi 6 is still relatively new, may I ask what you will be using it for as a daily driver ? I have a few suggestions I can link but the price is a bit more than what you have linked, is price a concern and I only ask what you will daily drive it with so I know what to suggest.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder also it might be hard finding a tablet/laptop that is actually capable of 4k, your ask is quite specific and only things I know that come close would be chromebooks. But let me know what you find and decide!